# Change jQuery-Mobile Attribute at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am trying to figure out a way of changing a jQuery-Mobile Attribute at runtime, specifically the data-icon value. Here is my HTML:

```
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" 
                    runat="server" 
                    data-role="button" 
                    data-transition="fade" 
                    data-theme="b" 
                    class="ui-btn-right" 
                    data-icon="delete" 
                    data-iconpos="right" 
                    href="#page1">HyperLink2</asp:HyperLink>
```

Here is what I tried in my Code Behind but I am not able to access that particular value:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.HyperLinkExit.Text = "Refresh";
        HtmlGenericControl HyperLinkItem = Master.FindControl("HyperLinkExit") as HtmlGenericControl;
        HyperLinkItem.data-icon = "refresh";
    }
```

I'm sure that there is some method that will allow me to change this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-icon` is not a property of `HtmlGenericControl`.  Use the `Attributes` property instead:

```
HyperLinkItem.Attributes["data-icon"] = "refresh";
```